# Error in reading file and uploading remotely in Android

Tags: java, android, http-post

My application asks user to choose a file which is uploaded to a PHP script. When the user selects a file, the correct URI is returned, but when I try to access the file, i get FileNotFound error. The following is the onActivityResult code:

```
private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 1234;    
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:      
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
                // Get the Uri of the selected file 
                Uri uri = data.getData();

                Log.d("file upload register page", "File Uri: " + uri.toString());
                try {
                file_path = FileUtils.getPath(getBaseContext(), uri);
            } 
                catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("file upload register page", "File Path: " + file_path);
            file = new File(file_path);
            UploadFile task = new UploadFile();
            task.execute();
        }           
        break;
    }
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

THe FileUtils.getPath function returns the path for a given URI. According to logs, my returned path is:
file:///mnt/sdcard/bluetooth/Tutorial%201.pdf

In the AsyncTask UploadFile, I am uploading the file to a remote server. I get an error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/mnt/sdcard/bluetooth/Tutorial%201.pdf (No such file or directory).
```

This is how I upload the file:

```
public void newUpload()
{
    HttpEntity resEntity;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(file), -1);
        reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
        reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response_http = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        //Do something with response...
        resEntity = response_http.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        Log.d("response",response);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How do I solve the file not found exception? I have no clue why is it not working!

Comment: When you do `new FileInputStream(file)`, what is the exact value of `file`? I don't think there should be a leading `/` in `/file:/mnt/sdcard/bluetooth/Tutorial%201.pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `getPath()` function. It might not be sending the correct path for the given URI.

Comment: you are right. the problem was  in the getPath() function itself.